# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'typeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular6, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

Anyone help because I try with the latest vision of 5.0.0 of ngx-bootstrap but still it is not working.

As i showed bellow I follow [official doc][1] steps but it is not working
In HTML:

```
  <input formControlName="Country"
    [typeahead]="Country"
    [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="7"
    [typeaheadMinLength]="0"
    [typeaheadAsync]="true"
    placeholder="Type here"
    class="form-control">
</div>


  [1]: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the ngx-bootstrap type ahead module into your module. Add TypeaheadModule to your imports section of your module.

Comment: `import { TypeaheadModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead'; imports:[TypeaheadModule.forRoot()]` i alredy done that

Answer (score 0):

By adding `[attr.typeahead]` problem is solved 
the solution is 
`<input formControlName="State"
          [attr.typeahead]="states"
          placeholder="Typeahead inside a form"
          class="form-control" />`

but 
the new issue is accord because of this new list is not appearing anyone know what this happens and how to solve it.